# How can I get jQuery load() to complete before fadeOut/fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to do an AJAX call via jQuery load() and only once it returns, then fadeOut the old content and fadeIn the new content. I want to old content to remain showing until the new content is retrieved, at which point the fade Out/In is triggered.

Using:

```
$('#data').fadeOut('slow').load('/url/').fadeIn('slow');
```

the content fades in and out and a few moments the later the load() call returns, and the data updates, but the fade has already completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use callbacks to the control the order of the calls.

```
var $data = $('#data');
$data.fadeOut('slow', function() { 
    $data.load('/url/', function() { 
        $data.fadeIn('slow'); 
    }); 
});
```

*(Note: I'm not 100% sure about if using* `var $data = ...` *and* `$data.doStuff()` *will actually work - if it does, it saves you from having to look up the div in the DOM tree every time, but if it doesn't, just remove the first line and use* `$('#data')` *everywhere...*

Comment: The above $data variable will be available in the other anonymous functions.

Comment: Are you saying that my disclaimer at the bottom can be removed? =)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to the fact that all three functions, fadeOut, load and fadeIn are asynchronous. Each of the above functions accept a callback argument (a function) which will run when the function has finished execution. E.g.

```
$('#data').fadeOut(functionToRunWhenFadeOutIsComplete);
```

//If you have defined 'functionToRunWhenFadeOutIsComplete' it will run after fadeOut is over.

Armed with this knowledge, you can now solve your problem.

```
var fadeInData = function fadeInData() { $('#data').fadeIn(); }
var loadData = function loadData() { $('#data').load('url', fadeInData); }
$('#data').fadeOut(loadData);
```

Alternatively, you can define loadData, fadeInData as an inline anonymous functions.